# «Второй сын Яков…» у Горького – это правильно?

Tags: пунктуация, приложение, уточнения

Речь идет о предложении, которое часто используется тестах по пунктуации: «Второй сын Яков, кругленький и румяный, был похож лицом на мать» (М. Горький).

Мне кажется, что правильно было бы так: Второй сын, Яков, кругленький и румяный, был похож лицом на мать. Или, например, так: Их сын Яков, кругленький и румяный, был похож лицом на мать.

Дело в том, что сочетание  «второй сын» однозначно определяет лицо, поэтом имя  Яков будет уточнением. А то получается, что у них два сына с именем Яков, первый и второй. Конечно, смысл текста ясен, но сомнительная грамматика напрягает слух. А то, что предложение используется в качестве единственно правильного  оформления  в тестах, тоже  не очень хорошо.

А как вы думаете, какой вариант верен? Или возможны оба?

Comment: Ещё пример с однозначным определением лица: *автор Моны Лизы(,) Леонардо да Винчи*.

Comment: Вы же не напишете так:  автор Моны Лизы Леонардо да Винчи? Тоже некорректно, он же автор многих произведений.

Comment: "он же автор многих произведений" — не понял мысль. В таких случаях хочется обособить. Но обязательно ли это? Два уточнения подряд — не очень хорошо (в примере Горького), но если о Якове идёт речь впервые, то для представления необходимо обособить (иначе нет представления). А если обособить "Яков", то глагол и следующее будет относиться ко "второй сын", а не ко главному — к "Яков". Кстати, можно по-разному прочитать: если ударение будет на "второй", то получится, что два Якова, а иначе читается нормально.

Comment: Ваш пример надо смотреть по ситуации,  но отдельное сочетание на слух кажется некорректным без запятой. Теперь о Якове.  Почему вам не нравится  два уточнения подряд, а Якова вы считаете главным?  Ведь содержание предложения при обособлении  вполне  ясное. Второй сын  (его, кстати, зовут Яков), кругленький и румяный, был похож лицом на мать. И (тоже кстати)  второе обособление имеет основной, а не уточняющий смысл – там же речь идет о внешности.

Comment: Просто имя более конкретно представляет человека, и далее лучше продолжать от него, но и ваша интерпретация нормальна. Потому что как вставка получается (*Яков, кругленький и румяный*), цепочка обособлений. Много обособлений — не есть хорошо.

Comment: Много обособлений — не есть хорошо? Ах,  oleedd, вы обобщенную теорию любите больше. чем конкретную практику. А ведь помните, наверное, что теория суха, а древо жизни пышно зеленеет.

Comment: Красиво сказано)))

Comment: Если следовать Розенталя, запятая все же не нужна

Comment: Елизавета Алексеевна поехала погостить к брату, Аркадию Алексеевичу; Он сына моего, Борьку, напомнил ***(есть только один брат, один сын; если бы было несколько, то при выражении той же мысли собственное имя не следовало бы обособлять);***

Comment: Серж, приветствую вас!  Розенталь учил нас гибкому мышлению  при решении задач по пунктуации, но так и не научил.  Он разбирал КОНКРЕТНЫЕ примеры, но мы хотим пользоваться его готовыми ответами во всех случаях – так мы понимаем Розенталя. Сейчас мне хочется уйти от этой точки зрения, да и время уже другое. В современной грамматике  на первое место ставится КОММУНИКАТИВНОСТЬ –  цель и адресат сообщения. С кем мы разговариваем, какую информацию хотим ему передать, что он уже знает о нас и т.д. Все это надо учитывать.

Comment: «Он сына моего () Борьку () напомнил…» При обособлении отвечающий уточняет имя, при отсутствии – дает всю информацию в основном сообщении. Почему он так поступает, с кем он разговаривает  – это мы можем видеть только по контексту. Его собеседник не будет делать выводы о составе семьи по обособлению – никому это не нужно. Возможно, персонаж просто для себя вспомнил дорогое ему имя,  тогда это выражение его эмоций.

Comment: Вот такой подход. А с Яковом другая ситуация, там АВТОР описывает семью, и описание получается неудачным. Мы понимаем содержание текста, но отсутствие уточнения (именно в этом предложении, так как дальше следует основное определение) нам кажется некорректным на слух.

Comment: Пока действуют эти правила. А если каждый будет исходить только из того, что звучит, а что не звучит на слух, что же получится?

Answer (score 1):

Я не исключаю, что вариант без запятой перед «Яковом» — простая опечатка в первом издании, поскольку таким образом именно что получаются два сына Якова, а это явный абсурд.

Вот, кстати, аналогичные примеры из «Хаджи-Мурата» Л. Толстого:

> Переводчик, князь Тарханов, подошел к Хаджи-Мурату и заговорил с ним.

> Хозяин сакли, Садо, был человек лет сорока...

Comment: Так вы со мной согласны? Спасибо!  А почему вы думаете, что это опечатка. Может, во времена Горького не было строгого правописания, вот и не заметили ошибку (если там действительное есть ошибка). А наши составители  тестов о чем думают?

Comment: Sharon, «строгого» в смысле «регламентированного на государственном уровне» правописания в те времена, возможно, и не было, но здравый смысл в какой-то мере всё же присутствовал. Были грамматические правила, которым учили в школе, были люди, с чувством языка, которые и тогда вполне могли обсудить между собой эту фразу: «А как по-вашему, не нужна ли вот здесь запятая?..» — «Да, думаю, запятая необходима, иначе получается вздор...» Но вообще-то грамматическая ошибка тогда была личным делом пишущего. Но всё равно была ошибкой!

Comment: А о чём думают составители тестов (и часто ли они думают вообще) — это уж вопрос к ним :)

Answer (score 1):

> Имущественное состояние Степана ― отца Ивана, когда у него родился
> третий сын Иван [О. П. Семенова-Тян-Шанская. Жизнь «Ивана». Очерки из
> быта крестьян одной из черноземных губерний (1885-1906)]

> Третий сын Мишка ныне ― ученик III класса гимназии, получает пятерки.
> [Ал. П. Чехов. Письма Антону Павловичу Чехову (1903)]

> «Третий сын Иван родился через год или два после реформы» ― этими
> словами начинается жизнеописание Ивана. [В. П. Шнейдер. Жизнь «Ивана».
> Вместо предисловия (1914)]

> Через четырнадцать лет, неожиданно для соседей, родился третий сын,
> Теодор: в это время Кемпфер был заворожен сионистическим учением
> Теодора Герцля: [Семен Липкин. Записки жильца (1962-1976)]
>
> Третий сын, Алексей, ― генерал-лейтенант авиации, продолжает летать на
> боевых самолетах, занимая командную должность. [Анастас Микоян. Так
> было (1971-1974)]

Написанный в 1925 году роман создавался по законам правописания своего времени.

Хронологически расставленные примеры дают такую подсказку: примерно до сер. XX столетия отношение к порядковому числительному в рассматриваемой связке было иным, — оно не могло влиять на пунктуацию таким образом, что нарицательное и личное шли бы отдельно, через запятую. И в этом был большой смысл.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение.  А какой именно смысл? Можно его кратко обозначить?

Comment: Нарицательное от личного не отделять. Это должно быть нормой.

Comment: shampar, вам всё ещё недостаточно «нормы»? :)

Comment: Не вводил бы, а оставил. Ну давайте такое сочиним: «То был мой по отцовской линии двоюродный дядя, Петя!» Это ж уродство, с выделением.

Comment: Sharon, я не думаю, что такая «норма» нам нужна, :) но я сейчас пишу не того, чтобы это сказать, а потому, что задумался: почему в первых трёх примерах (Семенова-Тян-Шанская и др.) отсутствие запятой не режет глаз так, как у Горького. И понял, что рядом с пояснительным оборотом «кругленький и румяный» не выделять в качестве аналогичного оборота «Якова» просто грех. Впрочем, и без пояснительного оборота отсутствие запятой перед именами там выглядит некоторым архаизмом, и лично я так не писал бы. Но ошибкой не выглядит — а вот у Горького выглядит! Вывод: на все случаи жизни норм не напасёшься :)

Comment: Да, Егор,  интересное у вас наблюдение. Пожалуй, многое зависит от конкретики. В каждом случае мы определяем лицо, но разными способами. Если не ставим запятую, то  нам важно все сочетание. В других же случаях второе слово явно уточняющее – если не поставить запятую, то это кажется ошибкой. Так получилось у Горького, где перечисляется состав семьи, и там мы видим сочетание «второй сын Яков», это и раздражает слух. Да еще дальше следует обособленное  основное определение «кругленький и румяный», которое выглядит как уточняющее.

Comment: Вот так важно то, что мы называем коммуникативностью сообщения  (очень перспективное направление в современной грамматике).  Нужно обязательно учитывать цель сказанного и возможную информированность адресата.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вариант точно корректный. Но нужно разобраться с оригинальным.

Тут дело в смысловой группировке:
*ВторОй {сын Яков}* || Ударение на первом слове. Два Якова. Абсурд. Предупреждать абсурдное восприятие (что так поймут) не сильно есть смысл.
*{Второй сын} Яков* || Задуманный вариант. Здесь похоже на "неоднородные подлежащие" (раз они оба однозначно определяют лицо).

Согласен, что проблема имеется. Но тут слишком очевиден подвох, чтоб Горький так тупонул. Думаю, что это было осознанное решение, связанное с нежеланием двух обособлений подряд, паузы перед "Яков" и логического ударения на слове "сын".

Мне кажется, что люди иногда так говорят (без паузы и уточнения) и при однозначном определении лица. Но не всегда это может быть уместно.

Comment: Вероятно, это действительно влияние времени, так что Горького не будем винить. А пока наши пользователи решают тесты, и нет у них никаких сомнений  https://otvet.mail.ru/question/225832436

Comment: А там в первом возможны два варианта.

Comment: «Уставшие после долгой дороги, мальчики моментально заснули».  По правилам запятая  здесь факультативна, но по структуре желательно ее поставить. В то же время вопрос этот не для теста, где требуется однозначность, в этом вы правы. Кто вообще эти тесты составляет? Иногда кажется, что роботы какие-то. Но раздражают даже больше не они, а отвечающие – они выглядят не лучше. Кукол дергают за нитки, на лице у них улыбки…   https://stihi.ru/2015/08/08/2296